# IPTables блокировка входящего/исходящего трафика по домену

Tags: iptables, centos7

Всем привет.

Возможно ли с помощью iptables заблокировать входящий/исходящий трафик, если запрос приходит с Referer: apps.social-chat.ru ?

Если есть возможность, то как это сделать?

Comment: Если это http (не https) запрос, то можно попробовать модулем string просто найти эту строку в пакете. Но вообще если это действительно http(s) то веб-сервер с этим легче справится

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Для шлюза можно так(к примеру):

```
iptables  -A FORWARD -s 192.168.0.0/24 -m string --string "apps.social-chat.ru" --algo kmp --to 65535 -j DROP
```

где -s ваша подсеть. или  ip

Для одной машины Forward заменяется на INPUT/OUTPUT (или оба сразу)